# glBindTexture - returns argument error

Tags: python-2.7, pyopengl

I am working on augmented reality project. So the user should use the Webcam, and to see the  captured video with a cube drawn on that frame.
And this is where I get stuck , when I try to use glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture_background) method, I get error:
(
ArgumentError: argument 2: : wrong type
GLUT Display callback  with (),{} failed: returning None argument 2: : wrong type
)
I am completely stuck, have no idea what to do . The project is done in Python 2.7 ,  am using opencv and PyOpenGl  3.1.0.

You can find code on this link :[click here](https://github.com/stefanplazic/agumentedreality)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting error! So I played around with your source code (by the way in the future you should probably just add the code directly to your question instead of as a separate link), and the issue is actually just one of variable scope, not glut or opengl usage. The problem is your `texture_background` variable does not exist within the scope of the `_draw_scene()` function. To verify this, simply try calling `print texture_background` in your `_draw_scene()` function and you will find it returns `None` rather than the desired integer texture identifier.

The simple hack-y solution is to just call `global texture_background` before using it **within your** `_handle_input()` **function**. You will also need to define `texture_background = None` in the main scope of your program (underneath your `##FOR CUBE FROM OPENGL` comment). The same global comment applies for `x_axis` and `z_axis`.

That being said, that solution is not really that great. The rigid structure required by GLUT with all of these predefined `glut*` functions makes it hard to structure code the way you might want to in terms of initializing your app. I would suggest, if you are not forced to use GLUT, to use a more flexible alternative, such as pygame, pysdl2 or pyqt, to create your context instead.